# RegExp unexpected behaviour when going toString and then back

Tags: javascript, regex, serialization, deserialization

I need to serialize some javascript regular expressions.

My plan is to use `.toString()` to serialize and then `new RegExp(string)` to deserialize, however this does not work as I would expect - the regex delimiters in the string `/` are escaped by `new RegExp()`. Here is an example:

```js
let regEx = /^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$/g;
console.log("Initial: " + regEx.source);
    
let regExString = regEx.toString();
console.log("toString(): " + regExString);
    
let nRegEx = new RegExp(regExString);
console.log("new RegExp from string:" + nRegEx.source);
```

returns the following:

```
"Initial: ^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$"
"toString(): /^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$/g"
"new RegExp from string:\/^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$\/g"
```

If I do this instead (`regEx.source.toString()`):

```js
let regEx = /^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$/g;
console.log("Initial: " + regEx.source);
    
let regExString = regEx.source.toString();
console.log("toString(): " + regExString);
   
let nRegEx = new RegExp(regExString);
console.log("new RegExp from string:" + nRegEx.source);
```

It results in:

```
"Initial: ^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$"
"toString(): ^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$"
"new RegExp from string:^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$"
```

Which is better but it looses all my flags, in this instance `/g`

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: It isn't... This is just an example. The input is irrelevant, ideally I want to serialize the flags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you could split the `toString` result into RE and modifiers, like:

```js
let regEx = /^[A-Z][A-Z-\\.]+$/g;
console.log("Initial: " + regEx.source);
    
let regExString = regEx.toString();
console.log("toString(): " + regExString);

let arrRegEx = regExString.split('/');

let nRegEx = new RegExp(arrRegEx[1], arrRegEx[2]);
console.log("new RegExp from string:" + nRegEx.source);
console.log("global: " + nRegEx.global ? 'true' : 'false');
```

(Note using split leaves the first index empty. Hence index 1 and 2 as input to the `new`.)

**Edit**

The above will fail if there are litteral `/`'s in the RE. Using a regex to extract the parts will fix that:

```js
    let regEx = /^[A-Z][A-Z-\/\\.]+$/gi;
    console.log("Initial: " + regEx.source);
        
    let regExString = regEx.toString();
    console.log("toString(): " + regExString);

    let arrRegEx = /^\/(.*)\/([gmi]*)/.exec(regExString);
    console.log("RegEx:" + arrRegEx[1] + ", flags:" + arrRegEx[2]);

    let nRegEx = new RegExp(arrRegEx[1], arrRegEx[2]);
    console.log("new RegExp from string:" + nRegEx.source);
    console.log("global: " + nRegEx.global);
    console.log("ignoreCase: " + nRegEx.ignoreCase);
    console.log("multiline: " + nRegEx.multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) and [`.flags`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags) properties from original regex object to construct a new `RegExp` object:

```js
let regEx = /^[A-Z][A-Z\\.-]+$/g
console.log(regEx.toString())
//=> /^[A-Z][A-Z\\.-]+$/g

let nRegEx = new RegExp(regEx.source, regEx.flags)
console.log(nRegEx.toString())
//=> /^[A-Z][A-Z\\.-]+$/g
```

Comment: This won't work in all browsers though (e.g. IE, Edge).

Comment: erm... the second regex is not created using the string returned from the first one...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia: 2nd regex is constructed from `regEx.source` and `regEx.flags` where `regEx` is first object.